# Ctrl+Shift+Tab in sometimes registers Ctrl+w, Ctrl+c, and Ctrl+x

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

- Running Ubuntu 16.04
- I've switched <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> and <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> on my keyboard using gnome-tweak-tool
- Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> *should* do just that
- Instead, I have confirmed using a key logging utility that it *additionally* registers <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> (and combined with the shift key, this creates <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> which quits the application
- Seems to work or not work at random -- sometimes, it happens every time, other times, it doesn't do it at all
- Very annoying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be the keyboard itself. A different keyboard didn't have this problem.

Comment: congratulations on the successful troubleshooting. ( it adds to another reason to move from normal keyboard to an established brand keyboard )

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> quits Chrome, you may be hitting <kbd>Q</kbd> accidentally instead of <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Here's a tip from [this reddit thread dealing with exactly this issue](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/39jdxt/i_hate_crtlshiftq/):

> 1. Go to `chrome://extensions`
> 2. In the very bottom right, click *Keyboard shortcuts*
> 3. Rebind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to something less annoying

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'm certain that this isn't the problem. I've installed screenkey to get a recorded capture and it showed (well, one time at least) "Ctrl+x Ctrl+c Ctrl+w" when I pressed Ctrl+Shift+Tab. I switched out the keyboard to see if it was a hardware problem and I'm testing it out now.